# VRF-like multiple routing tables on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, networking, routing

Does modern Windows kernel support some kind of VRF-like (or Linux network namespaces) multiple routing tables?

I am considering a Windows server with 5 NICs. Every NIC attached to its own VRF context. Within every VRF, one default route pointing to a gateway. Application software should be able to bind to IP address within its VRF.

I can't really use plain virtualization because Windows should actually run as guest already within VM instance. Then I need multiple routing tables within the Windows guest.

My research have not hit anything useful so far. I'm afraid Windows currently cannot handle anything similar to multiple routing tables. Is this correct?

NOTE: Asked on [Super User](http://superuser.com) without success: https://superuser.com/questions/1022407/vrf-like-multiple-routing-tables-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

This page shows up as the second result in a Google on "windows vrf". So even though it is old, to help others who also visit it, see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/sdn/manage/understanding-usage-of-virtual-networks-and-vlans which says:

Additionally, each tenant is assigned a routing domain (similar to virtual routing and forwarding - VRF) so that multiple virtual subnet prefixes (each represented by a VNI) can be directly routed to each other. Cross-tenant (or cross routing domain) routing is not supported without going through a gateway.